# Woocommerce - Avada theme - add price to search results page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add the price field from woocommerce to the search results screen for an Avada template.  Currently it only shows the featured image and product excerpt.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this with Avada. It's not as simple as going in to the `search.php` template file and editing it (so I found out).

I tried editing `search.php` file, checking all avada options, and searching Google for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with below code:

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    

    <?php
    
    $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true );

    
    if ( ! empty( $price ) ) {
        echo '<p>Price: ' . $price . '</p>';
    }
    ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What file am I supposed to be editing?  

I did some more research yesterday and it looks like Avada seems to use its own template files along with other dynamic data to make a search results page so not sure if this will work.

Comment: You add this code in the search.php

Comment: Doesnt work.. seems any HTML I add to the search.php page isnt showing... so I assume it's not using this file.

Comment: You can check archive.php or index.php for the same.

Comment: Still doesnt work.. it seems editing any of these files makes no difference to search results.